# Opencart to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opencart, opencart-3

I want to transfer my customer data **Opencart to Wordpress** user

in Opencart Password, the mechanism is **MD5+salt** and Wordpress have only **MD5**

is there any way to transfer my customer login data Opencart to Wordpress

Not sure how can I achieve this.

Please don't suggest any tool.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the password mechanisms are different so a direct transfer would not be possible. I can think of two possible workarounds that may help:

1) In addition to the md5 + salt method, Opencart will *also* accept a plain md5 hashed password as well.  You could add a couple lines of code in to customer library to convert those passwords to plain md5 hashes like this.

<sup>*Note: The exact placement and syntax depend on your Opencart version which you did not provide. This example is for v2.3.0.2*</sup>

Open the library class (`system/library/cart/customer.php`) and look for the `login()` function.  Below that find a line of code like this:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer_id . "'");
```

Change it like so:

```
$this->db->query("
    UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer
    SET language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "',
        ip = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "',
        password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "'
    WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer_id . "'
");
```

Now every time someone logs in their password will be converted to something readable by plain md5 hash.  Obviously this would require customers to log in once before the password would be updated.

2) Another possibility would be to modify the Wordpress authentication engine to work the same as Opencart.  I'm not a Wordpress expert but I doubt it would be difficult with a little research.